# Design question: is it okay for a class to have fields and their getters/setters that may be not always active and sanely called

Tags: c++, qt, oop, design-patterns

I have a class (let us call it `State`) representing some state. There are several fields in this state class. And there are getters/setters for these fields. But some of the fields can be accessed properly/sanely only when a `bool` **field** (let us call it `_flag`) is `true`. I mean some fields of the state are active and make sense only when the field `_flag = true`.

As the class is private, currently I solve the problem by having `Q_ASSERT(true == _flag)` at the beginning of all the getters/setters of the dependent fields. If the class was public, I would just have exceptions instead of assertions.

What I don't like is that I thus have quite many `Q_ASSERT(true == flag)` statements thrown across the class definition:

```cpp
int State::getA() const 
{
    Q_ASSERT(true == _flag);
    return _a;
}

// etc.
```

Is it okay and how people normally do or is anything wrong with my architecture?

**UPDATE**

In comments, I was told that I should elaborate on my question. I will do my best. The class state is a nested private class containing data for authentication. Here is its simplified version:

```cpp
    class AuthState
    {
    public:
        explicit AuthState(const QString& serverName, bool isConnectOn)
            :_isConnectOn(isConnectOn)
        {
            _serverUrls = {/*generate depending on serverName*/};

             if (isConnectOn)
             {
                 _connectCounts.resize(_serverUrls.size());
             }
        }

        QString getServerUrl() const
        {
            return _serverUrls[_urlIndex];
        }

        void setNextServerUrl()
        { 
            ++_urlIndex;
        }

        quint32 getConnectCount() const
        {
            Q_ASSERT(true == _isConnectOn);
            return _connectCounts[_urlIndex];
        }

        void incConnectCount()
        {
            Q_ASSERT(true == _isConnectOn);
            ++_connectCounts[_urlIndex];
        }

    private:
        int _urlIndex{0};
        QVector<QString> _serverUrls;
        QVector<quint32> _connectCounts;
        const bool _isConnectOn;
    };
```

Comment: its not clear how private or public changes something. Can you provide a [mcve]? I also dont understand what is the danger of getting an `int`

Comment: chances are high that there is something wrong with your design. If some instances have a member and some don't then why are they of the same type?

Comment: looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You navigated yourself into a position that is uncomfortable because you have to write code that you dont want to write. Why you need that code in the first place is unclear

Comment: I have updated my question @463035818_is_not_a_number . I have not yet read your answer. Have just noticed it. Thank you!

Comment: As @463035818_is_not_a_number has pointed out, the question is on "design" probably.  I just kinda don't know how I can ask it in a better way. I will try to come up with a better name for the question.

Comment: I think [`QVariant`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) can be a good reference. If the underlying data is of type `QString`, calling `toInt()` would still return some value, though it would not make sense. The class also provide `canConvert()` to indicate if the conversion can be made.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).